# How to create a dictionary that only allows objects that contains a certain value matching the dictionary key

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, enums

Given multiple instances of the same class that have different properties of a common emum, how can I create a dictionary with the keys of the given enum that will only allow a class that contains the enum value matching that key? For example, given the following code:

```
public enum Slot {Head, Torso, Legs}

public class Armor
{
   Slot slot;
}
```

How could I create a dictionary that given a key of `Slot.Torso` will only allow a value that is an `Armor` class with a `slot` property of `Slot.Torso`.

If not a dictionary, is there any other way to express this in C#?

Thanks

Comment: Simply use a normal dictionary and check the key and value before adding an entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking for compile time safety. Therefore, I suggest using generics to solve this problem.

Define a base class for your Slot types and implementations thereof:

```
public abstract class Slot { }

public sealed class Head : Slot { }
public sealed class Torso : Slot { }
public sealed class Legs : Slot { }
```

Your Armor implementation could then look something like this:

```
public abstract class Armor { }

public sealed class Armor<TSlot> : Armor
    where TSlot : Slot, new()
{
    public TSlot Slot { get; }
    public Armor() => Slot = new TSlot();
}
```

The relevant bit is that you only allow for generic instances being created with a specific type of slot. The new() constraint was only added to keep my sample code short.

Now you're ready to create your restrictive and compile time safe implementation of a dictionary for Armor instances using any Slot as key:

```
public sealed class SafeDictionary
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Slot, Armor> _dictionary = new Dictionary<Slot, Armor>();
    public Armor this[Slot slot] => _dictionary[slot];
    public void Add<TSlot>(TSlot slot, Armor<TSlot> armor)
        where TSlot : Slot, new()
    {
        _dictionary.Add(slot, armor);
    }
}
```

Usage is free with regard to what key value pairs you add:

```
    var head = new Armor<Head>();
    var torso = new Armor<Torso>();
    var torsoKey = new Torso();
    var dictionary = new SafeDictionary();
    dictionary.Add(head.Slot, head);
    dictionary.Add(torsoKey, torso);
    Console.WriteLine(torso == dictionary[torsoKey]);
    // Do not compile:
    // dictionary.Add(torsoKey, head);
    // dictionary.Add<Torso>(torsoKey, head);
```

This allows you to use any number of keys (Slots) with any number of values (Armors). As your requirement it is not possible to add an Armor instance with a Head slot using a Torso key. (And any other incompatible combination).
The price you pay is the need of one marker interface (Slot, here as abstract class) and in this example an empty implementation of Armor. If you'd like to regain the Slot property on Armor it can be done by adding an interface IArmor. There would also be options to restrict the Head, Torso and Legs instances to singletons to come closer to your example of using enums, but that's out of scope here.

I hope the above solution gives you enough material to solve your problem and develop the solution that best fits your needs.

Comment: @James Wilkinson: I saw you had posted a comment to my answer. It appears you've deleted it already. I'll try to answer what I remember. You said you're getting compilation errors. In principle that's what my soloution is after: providing a design that let's the compiler detect errors instead of detecting them only at runtime. If you're new to generics, it's normal to at first run into all sorts of compilation errors, you possibly didn't run into before. But in effect that's exactly what we're after: we (I) wan't the compiler to detect errors for me.

Comment: The above is only a skeleton design, so it is still incomplete. If you like you could add more specific requirements. Then we could try to refine the design a bit more. One question I'd have is whether it was your intenion only allowing three instances of Armor to be added to the dictionary? (one for each slot type) Or would you like to be able to add an arbitrary amount of Armor instances? BTW: Generics takes a while to get used to. But once fully mastered, I would not want to do without. The code is so much more expressive and powerful... (I very rarely use enums anymore...)

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
public enum Slot { Head, Torso, Legs }

public interface IArmor
{
    Slot SlotType { get; }
}

public class Torso : IArmor
{
    public Slot SlotType { get => Slot.Torso; }
}

public class Slots
{
    private Dictionary<Slot, IArmor> _slots { get; set; } = new Dictionary<Slot, IArmor>();

    public void Add(Slot slot, IArmor slotClass)
    {
        if (slot == slotClass.SlotType)
        {
            _slots.Add(slot, slotClass);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid type.");
        }
    }
}
```

And instance like:

```
var slots = new Slots();
slots.Add(Slot.Torso, new Torso());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an enum with the class names you want to whitelist. Then use reflection to create an instance of those and compare their type with the type of the property. Your property can be of type *object* and then you may either cast it to the type of class being tested, or check it's current type.

Something along those lines:

```
public enum WhitelistedTypes
{
    Head = 1,
    Torso = 2,
    Legs = 3,
}

var armorInstance = new Armor();
var asm = typeof(Armor).Assembly;
foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(WhitelistedTypes)))
{
    var typeName = ((WhitelistedTypes)item).ToString();                
    var objectType = typeof(Armor).Assembly.CreateInstance("SlotNamespace." + typeName).GetType();
    if(armorInstance.Slot.GetType() == objectType)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```